# Mobile Android Chrome not scrolling website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am working on a website and the scrolling to the about section on android mobile devices does not work. I am restricted by something and I do not know what. I have searched through overflow hoping for a solution but all suggestions have not worked. Here is my test website link: [Testing Website](http://nerdodevelopmenttesting.unaux.com/?i=1)

and here is the main CSS:

```
    html
{
  overflow: scroll;  
}

/*PARALLAX CSS */
.paral
{
    min-height: 600px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
}
.paral-about
{
    min-height: 100px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 200vw;
    height: 20vh;
    background-image: url(images/about_image.jpeg);
}
.paral p
{
    font-size: 4vh;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}
.paral h1
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    word-wrap:normal;
}
.paral strong
{
    color:skyblue;
}
.paral-padded
{
    padding-top: 20vh;;
}
.paral-home-setting
{
    width: 45vw;
}

/*Image for Parallax Section */
.paralhome
{
    background-image:url(images/home_image.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.paralabout
{
    background-color: black;
}
.paralservice
{
    background-color: blue;
}
.paralpricing
{
    background-color: purple;
}
.paralcontact
{
    background-color: magenta;
}
/*JUMBOTRON*/
.jumbotron
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*NAVIGATIONAL CSS*/
.nav-right
{
    padding-right: 10vw;
}
.nav-left
{
    padding-left: 10vw;
}
.nav-text-font
{
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}
/*Homepage Button CSS */
.btn-home-margin
{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:200px;
}

/*Other Stationary Rules*/
.normalized-padding
{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

and here is the media query CSS:

```
    /*For Regular Laptops*/
@media screen and (max-width:1440px)
{
    body
    {
    }
    .paral
    {
    min-height: 60vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    }
    .paral-padded
    {
        padding-top: 12vh;;
    }
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 5vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 60vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:6vh;
        width:43vh;
        font-size: 3vw;
    }
    .nav-right
    {
        padding-right: 10vw;
        font-size: 1.5vw
    }
    .nav-left
    {
        padding-left: 10vw;
        font-size: 1.8vw
    }

}
/*For Larger Tablets*/
@media screen and (max-width:1024px)
{
    body
    {
    }
    .paral
    {
        min-height: 60vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height:100vh;
    }
    .paral-padded
    {
        padding-top: 12vh;;
    }
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 6vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 60vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:5vh;
        width:30vh;
        font-size: 4vw;
    }
    .nav-right
    {
        padding-right: 10vw;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .nav-left
    {
        padding-left: 10vw;
        font-size:22px;
    }


}
/*For Regular Tablets*/
@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
    body
    {
    }
    .paral
    {
        min-height: 60vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height:100vh;
    }
    .paral-padded
    {
        padding-top: 12vh;;
    }
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 8vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 70vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:5vh;
        width:40vh;
        font-size: 6vw;
    }
    .nav-right
    {
        padding-right: 10vw;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .nav-left
    {
        padding-left: 10vw;
        font-size:22px;
    }


}
/*For Regular Smartphones*/
@media screen and (max-width:420px)
{
    body
    {
    }
    .paral
    {
        min-height: 60vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height:100vh;
    }
    .paral-padded
    {
        padding-top: 12vh;;
    }
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 9vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 80vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:6vh;
        width:30vh;
        font-size: 6vw;
    }
    .nav-right
    {
        padding-right: 10vw;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .nav-left
    {
        padding-left: 10vw;
        font-size:22px;
    }


}
/*For Older Smartphones*/
@media screen and (max-width:420px)
{
    body
    {
    }
    .paral
    {
        min-height: 60vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height:100vh;
    }
    .paral-padded
    {
        padding-top: 14vh;;
    }
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 9.5vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 85vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:4vh;
        width:32vh;
        font-size: 5vw;
    }
    .nav-right
    {
        padding-right: 10vw;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .nav-left
    {
        padding-left: 10vw;
        font-size:22px;
    }


}
```

I am not understanding in the slightest on why this problem is occuring. I have tried the overflow-y:scroll; and that didn't work(I put that code in both body of CSS and mediacss. Any suggestions would be most appreciative! Thanks!